# My jquery code opens only single tab

Tags: jquery, firebug

I'm running the following commands in firebug console with : http://www.tataphoton.com/customer-service.aspx with "Photon Pro" in the first combo and Go pressed once.

```
var chk = [];   
$("#comState_city option").each(function() {        chk.push($(this).val());    });

for(i=0;i<5;++i){
if(i>0){
$("#form1").attr("target","_blank");
$("#comState_city option:eq(0)").attr("value",chk[i]);
$("#comState_city option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected");
$("#comState_city").trigger('change');
}
```

}

The problem is that, for each value in chk[] **I want it to open new tab for each circle automatically** as I had done many times with other websites. But in this case it opens only single tab.
If I copy paste the for loop another time, still single tab only is opened.

**What I'm trying to do**:
I want to copy paste for all contact details for each say "Photon Pro" and then for each circle within it. I want the jquery to open a new tab for each circle, then I'd save all the tabs using scrapbook and then extract them using perl script.

Answer (score 0):

don't use blank. change your target to something dynamic like "window_"+i or something

Comment: come to think of it , _blank should open a lot of tabs. mmm

Comment: Let it open as many, I'll save all of them at once using scrapbook extension.